# Frequency count per sub array or slice in a 3D NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, frequency

I am trying to get the frequency count (without the zeros) per sub-array in a numpy 3d-array. However, the scipy.stats.itemfreq tool returns the frequency count in a 2d array.

What I get is:

```
array_3d= array([[[1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 3],
    [3, 3, 3]],

   [[0, 0, 4],
    [0, 0, 4],
    [0, 0, 4]]])

>>> itemfreq(array_3d)[1:,]
# outputs
array([ 1,  2],
   [ 2,  1],
   [ 3,  4],
   [ 4,  3]], dtype=int64)
```

While I would like the output:

```
array([[ 1,  2, 2, 1],
   [ 3,  4],
   [ 4,  3]], dtype=object)
```

The idea is that the uneven number is always the unique value and the even number the frequency.

Another output could be:

```
array([ 1,  2, 0],
   [ 2,  1, 0],
   [ 3,  4, 1],
   [ 4,  3, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Where the third column represents the subset number in the 3d array.

I am also open to other outputs/solutions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe the higher level problem which you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) can be used to solve this problem in an elegant and vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
index = np.arange(array_3d.size) // array_3d[0].size
(value, index), count = npi.count((array_3d.flatten(), index))
```

This then gives:

```
index = [0 0 0 1 1 2 2]
value = [0 1 2 0 3 0 4]
count = [6 2 1 5 4 6 3]
```

Which can be postprocessed by indexing with value > 0 if so desired

Comment: I think OP is looking for count per sub-array or slice. So that `flatten` would contradict the desired output.

Comment: Which is what this example does; what is counted are unique combinations of 'array_3d.flatten()' and 'index'

Comment: Ah I see! Nice. What about avoiding the zeros? Avoid the first element of the output?

Comment: I think the most elegant way of dealing with that would be to postprocess with count[value>0]

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Get unique non-zero elements
unq = np.unique(array_3d[array_3d!=0])

# Get matches mask corresponding to all array_3d elements against all unq elements
mask = array_3d == unq[:,None,None,None]

# Get the counts
sums = mask.sum(axis=(2,3)).T

# Indices of non-zero(valid) counts
Rvalid,Cvalid = np.where(sums!=0)

# Finally, pressent the output in the desired format
out = np.column_stack((unq[Cvalid],sums[sums!=0],Rvalid))
```

Please note that this would be a resource hungry method.

**Approach #2**

Here's another approach that is less resource hungry and as such might be preferred -

```
a2d = np.sort(array_3d.reshape(array_3d.shape[0],-1),axis=1)
start_mask = np.column_stack((a2d[:,0] !=0,np.diff(a2d,axis=1)>0))

unqID = a2d + ((np.arange(a2d.shape[0])*a2d.max())[:,None])
count = np.unique(unqID[a2d!=0],return_counts=True)[1]
out = np.column_stack((a2d[start_mask],count,np.where(start_mask)[0]))
```

Please note that the `count` could be alternatively calculated with `np.bincount` and might be faster, like so -

```
C = np.bincount(unqID[a2d!=0])
count = C[C!=0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This method works perfect wen array_3d is relatively small. However, my array_3d has 89528 sub arrays. Most likely, this is the reason why the mask is not working, as the mask array simply gets to big.

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren Yeah this would be resource hungry method for sure.

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren Could you check out the just added second approach? Thanks!

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas  give intuitive way to this result too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array_3d.reshape(3,9))
stats = df.apply(lambda x : unique(x,return_counts=True),axis=1)
result = stats.apply(lambda x : vstack(x)[:,1:].ravel())
```

For

```
#stats
0    ([0, 1, 2], [6, 2, 1])
1          ([0, 3], [5, 4])
2          ([0, 4], [6, 3])

#result
0    [1, 2, 2, 1]
1          [3, 4]
2          [4, 3]
```